# How to remove (Android) app title bar in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin.forms

Is there any chance that I can remove the title bar of the app in Xamarin.Forms? I am working on a Xamarin.Forms Portable project. I tried a lot of solutions, but neither worked, I couldn't even start the app.

**First attempt** I tried adding this to my AndroidManifest.xml, didn't work:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

**Second attempt** I tried creating a styles.xml in Resources/values, which was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="Theme.Default" parent="@android:style/Theme"></style>
  <style name="Theme.NoTitle" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></style>
  <style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></style>
</resources>
```

And then I added this to my AndroidManifest.xml (didn't work either)

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoTitle"
```

**Third attempt** I tried adding this to my OnCreate method in MainActivity.cs (didn't work).

```
RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to remove the title bar on the initial page, the quickest and easiest way to do it is to go to to the contentpage heading in your XAML for the page and type

**NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"**

so the XAML would like something like this

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourClass.YourPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in PCL:

```
 var page = new LoginPage();
 NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false); // call this method every time before you push a page (no title bar)
 await navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

If you are using old FormsApplicationActivity,
try, add this in OnCreate(Bundle bundle) method

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle)

    Forms.SetTitleBarVisibility(AndroidTitleBarVisibility.Never);
    Forms.Init(this, bundle);
}
```

This one seems do the app wide setting, but I am not so sure, as I don't use FormsApplicationActivity anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure where I have to insert this code. Could you tell me where I should? I mean which file and which place (e.g. App.cs -> public App() method)

Comment: Did you edit it now? I can't see it, only the ones edited 10 hrs ago.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the PCL version yet, but the Android version works well, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest version of `Xamarin.Forms` I found that if you use:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage())
```

//Title on NextPage is displayed

```
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NextPage())
```

//Title on NextPage is not displayed

Nathan

Comment: This works well on my NextPage, but what about the page I navigate from?

Comment: This is the best answer especially when you have a first form which brings you to the next form with a Navigation Drawer

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem before and my solution was adding this line of code to the **MainPage.xaml** `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xf:BottomBarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:BottomBar.XamarinForms;assembly=BottomBar.XamarinForms"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App;assembly=App"
                         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" <-- This line !-->
                  x:Class="App.MainPage">
```

**and it worked for me !**

Answer (score 0):

```
Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Views;  // Webkit required for WebView

namespace LoadWebPage {
    [Activity(Label = "LoadWebPage", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS this single line (e.g. in the constructor of the page) works just fine.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page, false);
```

But Android is ignoring it, also when put in the XAML of the page.

As mentioned above by Bonelol this method has to be called each time before you push a page.
I use Prism, so I can't access the creation and push of a page.
So I just created a custom renderer for NavigationPage and put this line there. Maybe this will help someone else.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomNavigationRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(view, false);
            return base.OnPushAsync(view, animated);
        }                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 private ActionBar ab;
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ab = this.ActionBar;
            ab.Hide();
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, just found it in one of view xaml in flyout tab
`Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"`

`<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="YourClass.Views.YourPage" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">`