# Hiding title bar xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

Hello I am trying to get rid of the title bar I have tried a number of things:

adding and removing: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar`
adding:  `Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);` (before and after `base.OnCreate`)

I also tried to change the theme. Nothing seems to work.

Anyone who could have a possible different solution? I am quite new to coding

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove (Android) app title bar in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986754/how-to-remove-android-app-title-bar-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the attribute that you are looking for may be:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompact.NoActionBar
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompact.Light.NoActionBar
```

Doc:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.style.html#Theme_AppCompat_NoActionBar